# Convert grayscale uint8 image to RGB uint8 image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb, grayscale

I have a code to run, which uses an **original image** and a **mask image**. The code assumes that the original image is RGB, but my original image is gray scale. This must be the result of the MATLAB `whos` command when I run the code:

```matlab
Name           Size                Bytes  Class      Attributes

mask         308x206               63448  logical              
origImg      308x206x3            190344  uint8
```

The mask is produced by making part of the image white and the rest is black (in a simple software like windows paint).

I want to use a gray-scale image as the `origImg` and produce the mask from the `origImg` in windows paint, but the result of the MATLAB `whos` command is as follows when I want to use custom photos with attributes as I said:

```matlab
Name           Size                Bytes  Class    Attributes

mask         490x640x3            940800  uint8              
origImg      490x640              313600  uint8
```

I have to convert the `origImage` dimension to **x3** and remove the **x3** from the mask, and also convert its class from **unit8** to **logical**. In that case, I think that the code should work properly.

What should I do here in order to prepare the `origImg` and `mask` for that goal?

```matlab
origImg=imread('G:\the_path\to\my_custom\image.png');
mask=imread('G:\the_path\to\my_custom\image_mask.png');
% I have to do something here to make it work.
whos;
% Rest of the code...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly.

To make a RGB image out of a gray-scale image, which still shows up as a gray-scale image, you can use

```
origImg = repmat(origImg,1,1,3);
```

which just repeats your gray-scale image for every channel of the RGB image.

For the mask, you have to do the opposite. since I don't know your `image_mask.png` file, I assume that it is a RGB image that uses only black and white. In this case, all three channels are the same and you could simply use one of them for the mask, doesn't matter which one:

```
mask = mask(:,:,1);
```

To convert it to logical, use

```
mask=logical(mask);
```

Comment: Yes, you understood everything well. The `mask` is now as I want, but the `origImg` not. The `mask` is `490x640` _logical_ and ok, by applying those codes you wrote the `origImg` is now `600x800x9` _unit8_ but must be `490x640x3` _unit8_.

Comment: If you start with `origImg` as `490x640` as you said in your question, the `repmat`-line will change it to `490x640x3`. If this line changes your `origImg` to `600x800x9`, then `origImg` before was `600x800x3`, which is not grayscale image. You might need to update your question.

Comment: No no no, my mistake. The `origImg` was `490x640` and when I wrote the last comment I was getting the result of another image (which I was trying to convert a typical RGB png image to gray-scale to see if it helps or not). My question was correct and your answer was exactly right. Thank you.